# Apache2 Won't Reload: Looking for a File I Intentionally Deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, apache2

Okay, so I'm following a guide to get set up with a Rails production server, and it says the following in the Apache2 setup:

> We have to create a virtual host by creating a file in the "/etc/apache2/sites-available" directory (we will name it "site" - the file won't have any extension but it will be a text file).
>   $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/site (this will create the file named "site" - can be any name - AND open it for editing)
>
> Copy and paste this into that file (compare also with what the notes after installing mod_rails tells you):
>
> VirtualHost *:80>
>
> ServerName localhost
>
> ServerAlias localhost
>
> DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/site/public
>
> /VirtualHost>

When I was first testing the waters with Apache I did as it said, making a fake scaffolded Rails app called "site".  Now I want to use my real site, which we'll call "realthing."  So I did

```
# sudo mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/site /etc/apache2/sites-available/realthing
```

And put my new settings into the renamed file.  So far so good.

Then I went to restart Apache.  Problems begin.

```
# sudo a2ensite realthing
Enabling site realthing.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
service apache2 reload
```

Okay, I can do that.

```
# sudo service apache2 reload
apache2: Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
...fail!
```

Fail indeed.  Nothing I can seem to do can get this thing to restart without flipping out about the missing "site" file.  I check line 230 of /etch/apache2/apache2.conf for any specific references.  Nope:

```
Include sites-enabled/
```

It's a generic reference to the folder containing "site".  But no mention of "site".

So what's up?  How do I get Apache to forget about the fake site "site" and move on to the real thing "realthing"?  It's driving me insane that even a superuser reload is failing because Apache can't find a file that as far as I can tell it has no reason to expect to find.

Even a hard
    sudo service apache2 stop
and
    sudo service apache2 start
doesn't work.  Again with the

```
* Starting web server apache2
apache2: Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site: No such file or directory
Action 'start' failed.
```

This is driving me bonkers.  Any ideas?

```
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using Passenger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably still have a symlink from sites-enabled/site to the now missing sites-available/site